# "Confuse A & B" vs. "Confuse between A & B"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

The verb confuse Is sometimes (but not always) followed by the word "between", which leaves me a bit... well, confused. Is there a difference in meaning between saying, for example, that an author (or an argument) "confused between A and B"(when A and B stand for different phenomena) and saying that they "confused A and B"? Is one of them stylistically superior to the other?

Comment: I never heard "confused between A and B," because we might confuse one thing *for* the other, but not between. Confused A and B works. Confused **A & B** is not the best idea, because the & pairs things closely right where you want to separate them. Ampersand fills in for *and* only in limited cases, not this one.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It seems entirely justified to say "between", as you say commonly enough "a confusion between A an B": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20confusion%20between%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of American English, I would say that someone "confused A *with* B."

I might also say, on the other hand, that "there was some confusion on [someone]'s part *between* A and B."

Notice that when I use *between*, it does not immediately follow the verb (or verb phrase) as in your example. That is because the word *between*, a preposition introducing a prepositional phrase, does not function well as a direct object. Instead, it functions as an adjective modifying the noun *confusion*.

If you want a direct object to follow the verb *confused*, my first example works better, being more concise.